# Hibernate validator produces different response for nested validation objects

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, hibernate-validator

I am using Hibernate validator in a Quarkus REST API project to validate entities with annotated properties after being parsed from JSON in my endpoints. Throughout the development, i came to expect that Hibernate Validator throws `ConstraintViolationException`s with a set of constraint violations resulting in responses in the following format:

```
{
  "title": "Constraint Violation",
  "status": 400,
  "violations": [
    {
      "field": "createJob.arg0.sourceTableName",
      "message": "Source database table name may not be blank"
    },
    {
      "field": "createJob.arg0.sourceTableName",
      "message": "Source database table name should have size [1,256]"
    },
    {
      "field": "createJob.arg0.sourceDatabaseURL",
      "message": "Source database URL should have size [1,256]"
    }
  ]
```

}

This example is for a the `JobRequest` entity with only simple data types or not having other entities nested yet. This works well and my frontend client has been programmed accordingly to expect such a response format for **HTTP 400 Bad Request** responses. However, i now have the case where i need to add another entity called `Settings` (with its own validation annotations etc.) as a nested property to `JobRequest`. Example:

```
@GroupSequenceProvider(JobRequestSequenceProvider.class)
public class JobRequest {
    @Transient
    private Optional<Boolean> useLocalSourceDatabase;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256, message = "Source database URL should have size [{min},{max}]", groups = SourceConditionalValidation.class)
    @URL(message = "Source database connection has to be a valid URL", groups = SourceConditionalValidation.class)
    private String sourceDatabaseURL;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256, message = "Source database table name should have size [{min},{max}]", groups = SourceConditionalValidation.class)
    @NotBlank(message = "Source database table name may not be blank", groups = SourceConditionalValidation.class)
    private String sourceTableName;

    @Transient
    private Optional<Boolean> useLocalTargetDatabase;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256, message = "Target database URL should have size [{min},{max}]", groups = TargetConditionalValidation.class)
    @URL(message = "Target database connection has to be a valid URL", groups = TargetConditionalValidation.class)
    private String targetDatabaseURL;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256, message = "Target database table name should have size [{min},{max}]", groups = TargetConditionalValidation.class)
    @NotBlank(message = "Target database table name may not be blank", groups = TargetConditionalValidation.class)
    private String targetTableName;

    // Here i add settings as a nested property and force validation of it
    @Valid
    private Settings settings;

    // get/set...
}
```

*(JobRequest + Settings entity as a nested property)*

I was expecting the same response format in cases of constraint violations of either the top level entity `JobRequest` or nested entity `Settings`, however the response format i receive for constraint violations in the nested `Settings` entity look like this:

```
{
  "objectName": "JobRequest",
  "attributeName": "settings.requestDelayInMiliseconds",
  "line": 1,
  "column": 470,
  "value": "fsdf"
}
```

Not only does it have a different schema, but it is also inadequate as it always just returns ONE violation and not multiple if thats the case for the `Settings` entity. In fact, it even overrides the constraint violations in the parent entity (`JobRequest`) for the response.

What is going on here? **How can i get Hibernate Validator to perform the same type of validation (with according exceptions and ultimately error responses) for entites with nested entities?**

---

Here is the `Settings` entity for reference (for which validation by itself works perfectly fine as expected with `ConstraintViolationException`s - this strange behaviour only occurs for when entities get nested):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "settings", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"is_default"}) })
public class Settings extends BaseEntity {
    @NotNull
    @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 5)
    @Min(value = 1)
    @Column(name = "request_limit_before_delay", nullable = false)
    private int requestLimitBeforeDelay = 0;
    
    @NotNull
    @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 5)
    @Min(value = 1, message = ERROR_MESSAGE)
    @Column(name = "request_delay_in_miliseconds", nullable = false)
    private int requestDelayInMiliseconds = 0;

    @Column(name = "is_default", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Boolean isDefault = null;
    // get/set...
}
```

Comment: If you have this problem in the context of Quarkus, could you open a Quarkus issue here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues with a small Maven reproducer? I will have a look. Thanks!

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet Thanks for your response! I did not think about that this could be a quarkus related issue, but i will try to get to it ASAP! Much appreciated.